# java: call external jar program (-> 'create process error')

Tags: java, jar, runtime, exec, executable-jar

I'm trying toopen/execute another program, which is a .jar file, but I'm getting the following error:

> it is not a windows application

(java.io.IOException: **CreateProcess error=193**)

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            String filepath = "C://Users//Alex//Desktop//Speedtest.jar";

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filepath);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the command-line, JARs are executed with `java -jar`.  Try passing a String array:

```
String[] args = new String[] {"java", "-jar", "/path/to/myJar.jar"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
```

Comment: ok i tried this and there is still the same error, that it is no windows program:

Comment: Cannot run program "Speedtest.jar": CreateProcess error=193, %1 ist keine zulässige Win32-Anwendung
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)